# Find out which motherboards officially support a specific memory model (in their QVL)

Tags: memory, motherboard

Finding which memory are officially supported by a specific motherboard model is easy, via it's QVL. My case is sort of a reversed one. My old mobo is gone and I have to buy a new one, so I already have the memories (Corsair Vengeance 8GB DDR3 1600MHz CL8).

I don't know if this is worth the effort, but is there any way I can find which motherboards have my memory model in their QVL? Hope it's obvious that 'brute force' search isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If they still sell your model of ram you can try [PCPartPicker](http://pcpartpicker.com/parts/partlist/) to find compatible motherboards.